# Prevent div from moving downward when preceding div resizes

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a basic email capture form but I can't figure out the CSS to prevent the Submit button from moving when an error message is shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaidv.jpg

I am building this using React.js, and tried to use flexboxes, aligning the contents of the column along the top.  Here is the html snippet from my component, I am using [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) for the text field and submit button:

```
 <div className='row'>
   <form className='registration' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     <div className='column'>
       { !this.props.registered && 
        <TextField
         hintText='example@domain.com' 
         errorText={this.props.errorText}
         value={this.props.email} 
         onChange={this.handleChange}
         onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
       /> }   
     </div>
     <div className='column'>
       { this.props.verifying &&
        <CircularProgress 
          size={25} 
          visible={this.props.verifying} 
          color={grey500} 
        /> }
       { !this.props.verifying && !this.props.registered &&              
        <RaisedButton type='submit' label='Submit'
       /> }
     </div>
   </form>
   <style jsx>{`
     .row {
       display: flex;
     }
     .column {
       flex: 1;
       padding: 1rem;
       display: inline;
       vertical-align: top;
     }
  `}</style>
 </div>
```

Here are screenshots of what the rendered markup looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak7sP.jpg.  It appears the column div is in the right place, but the markup rendered in place of  is still sliding down.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Hard to debug if we can't reproduce the problem. It's mainly guesswork at this point. See if you can provide a live demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the button is inside another div, and then just `float: left` both containers, you can see a live example [here](https://codepen.io/valecarlos/pen/rmjPew), another option is to make them `display : inline-box` with `vertical-align: top`

Both ways will give you an independent behavior on both your containers